# How to iterate through an enumerate object and print all the index-item pairs using next() function?

Tags: python

I have the following program

```
enum1 = enumerate("This is the test string".split())
```

I need to iterate through enum1 and print all the index-item pairs by using next() function.

I try to get the index-item pairs by doing the following

```
for i in range(len(enum1)):
    print enum1.next()
```

It throws me an error showing `len()` can't be applied to an enumeration.

Could anyone suggest me any such way by which I would be able to iterate through this enum to print all the index-item pairs using `next()` function?

Note: My requirement is to use `next()` function to retrieve the index-item pairs

Comment: That's a strange requirement. Why do you have to use next() when a for loop is better?

Comment: @gnibller: I don't think Ava can answer -- there is not even an SO account yet.  Does anybody know how to regain access to a migrated question?

Answer (score 6):

simply use:

```
for i,item in enum1:
   # i is the index
   # item is your item in enum1
```

or

```
for i,item in enumerate("This is the test string".split()):
   # i is the index
   # item is your item in enum1
```

this will use the `next` method underneath...

Answer (score 4):

Given the weird requirement that you need to use the `next()` method, you could do

```
try:
    while True:
        print enum1.next()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

You don't know in advance how many items an iterator will yield, so you just have to keep trying to call `enum1.next()` until the iterator is exhausted.

The usual way to do this is of course

```
for item in enum1:
    print item
```

Furthermore, in Python 2.6 or above, calls to the `next()` method should be replaced by calls to the built-in function `next()`:

```
print next(enum1)
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question: she wants to get the index and the item. She should just iterate over the numeration, as shown in my answer bellow.

Comment: @rafalotufo: This uses `enum1` as defined in the question, so this will always yield the index and the item.  Moreover, I pretty sure the OP wants to explicitly use `next()` (for whatever reasons).

Answer (score 2):

If you like to keep the exception handler close to the exception you can do it this way

```
while True:
    try:
        print next(enum1)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
gen = enumerate((1, 2, 3))
try:
  while True:
    print gen.next()
except StopIteration:
  pass # end of the loop
```